# Changes to the KDE library prevent compiz 0.9.7.12 from compiling

Tags: compiz, application-development, kde, compiling, software-installation

I have been been following a tutorial on modifying existing compiz plugins, but run into the following error when compiling compiz-0.9.7.12:

```
In file included from /home/sre/rbrais/compiz-core-0.9.7.12/build/kde/window-decorator-kde4/moc_window.cpp:10:0,
from /home/sre/rbrais/compiz-core-0.9.7.12/build/kde/window-decorator-kde4/kde4-window-decorator_automoc.cpp:4:
   /home/sre/rbrais/compiz-core-0.9.7.12/build/kde/window-decorator-kde4/../../../kde/window-decorator-kde4/window.h:27:31: fatal error: kdecorationbridge.h: No such file or directory
   compilation terminated.
   make[2]: *** [kde/window-decorator-kde4/CMakeFiles/kde4-window-decorator.dir/kde4-window-decorator_automoc.o] Error 1
   make[1]: *** [kde/window-decorator-kde4/CMakeFiles/kde4-window-decorator.dir/all] Error 2
   make: *** [all] Error 2
```

According to the error, the program is missing the file 'kdecorationbridge.h'. This file should be contained in the kde-workspace package according to the kde API. The access settings of the file 'kdecorationbridge.h' has been changed from "public' to 'private' according to kde review board. Does this change in access settings prevent me from building compiz 0.9.7.12? Another user has run into the same problem on another discussion board. However, I could use some help understanding their solution. Do I merely install the kde-base pacakge, or must I modify the source code of the build file to access the kde-base package?

I am considering installing another version of compiz, but have not been able to determine the most stable version. If I can first install compiz, I will move on to modifying existing plug ins and develop my own. My end goal is to update a plug in developed for an earlier release of compiz to the latest release. Any answers to my compilation query, or links to resources on learning how to develop compiz tutorials would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are lacking of the correct headers to compile it. Do:

```
sudo apt-get install kde-workspace-dev
```

and the error will go away. Maybe you want to do:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep compiz
```

so you get all the build dependencies.